# Angular 4, Python

Tags: mysql, python, angular2

Добрый день, появилась задача разработки сервиса с фронтом на Ангуляре и бэкендом на Питоне. Видел много подобных материалов с использованием фреймворков(Джанго, Фласк).Но для меня Питон нужен только в качестве языка для SQL запросов. Попробовал получить результат, но, к сожалению, не получилось, поскольку необходимо отправить заголовки в ответе, но как это сделать не знаю.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8
import MySQLdb
import json
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="", db="university", charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM student"

cursor.execute(sql)

data =  cursor.fetchall()
json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii = False)
# print(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii = False))

def after_request(response):
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
  return response
db.close()
```

--------------service--------------------

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestService {
  // private headers: Headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getData(){

    return this.http.get("http://localhost/diplom/connect.py")
      .map(res=>{return res.json() });
  }
}
```

Помогите собрать файл с подключением к бд и отправкой основных заголовков, чтобы в дальнейшем импортировать его в файлы с другими запросами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам просто нужен посредник между клиентом и БД на основе HTTP запросов, то нужно поднять локальный сервер, который будет ловить поступающие запросы, совершать необходимые действия с БД и отправлять ответы в нужном виде. Для этого существует масса  фреймворков, из которых самый простой Flask.

Установка из командной строки:

```
pip install Flask
```

Пример простого сервера:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

# советую поставить этот флаг,
# тогда будет выводиться дополнительная информация об ошибках
app.debug = True

# перенаправляет запросы по адресу "/" на функцию ниже
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    # формируем ответ, HTML, JSON, что угодно
    resp = flask.Response("Hello, world!")
    # вешаем любые заголовки
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    # отправляем ответ
    return resp
```

Тогда подключение к БД будет в начале кода, а в обработчиках HTTP-запросов будут все Ваши запросы к БД.

Также можно по-разному обрабатывать разные типы запросов (`GET`, `POST`, etc), использовать URL аргументы и содержимое поступающего запроса. В общем, Flask это простой, но вполне полноценный фреймворк.

Полезные ссылки:

- [Документация Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org)
- Дополнительные материалы можно найти и на этом сайте по метке: [flask](/questions/tagged/flask)